# Errors with EXCEL-DNA - XlCall.xlcOnKey - Calling Method with Parameters - Registered Shortcut with Parameters

Tags: excel, keyboard-shortcuts, excel-dna

I would like to register a shortcut to a method with parameters.

This works (no parameters) with no side effects or errors

```
XlCall.Excel(XlCall.xlcOnKey, "^+{h}", "MyMethod");
```

These work but after my code is executed,  it seems like Excel is still looking for a workbook macro

```
XlCall.Excel(XlCall.xlcOnKey, "^+{h}", "MyMethod(222)");
XlCall.Excel(XlCall.xlcOnKey, "^+{h}", "@"MyMethod(""222"")");
```

> *ERROR*  Cannot run the macro MyMethod("222").  The macro many not be available in this workbook or all macros may be disabled.

Note that the error is AFTER MyMethod has cleanly executed (then exited) my C# code.

Is there any way for me to register a shortcut that calls a C# Method with parameters and does NOT get the error I describe?

Cheers!  Thanks!

Comment: I don't know how to add the parameters so that the xlcOnKey works. Macros with parameters are inconsistently supported by Excel. I assume you only know the desired parameter at runtime. But registering a no-parameter macro for the shortcut, and have this call the 'real' macro with a parameter value that has been set at runtime should be fine. In extreme, it is also possible to make and register a macro method at runtime that you can then attach the shortcut to, but I can't see that being helpful. So there are various straight-forward workarounds for what I know as a frustrating Excel quirk.

Comment: Thanks Govert!!   Always appreciate your answers.   I had some "hacked" ideas for workarounds and I'll go with one of those.